# Retrieving records from table where a column may have multiple rows of data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access-2010

I have a database with several tables and I am using the following query to return a record that matches a string(Name).

In the `MHP` table there is a `Name field(primary key), Num_Sites` and a few more, but these are the only ones I am concerned with.

In the `MHP_Parcel_Info` table there are many fields with one of them being `Name(foreign key)`.  There is a `parcel_id` field and in some case there may only be one parcel for one name, but there may also be many parcels for a Name.

As it is now my query will return one of the rows for instances where there are multiple parcels for a name.

What I would like to do is: if there is more than one parcel for a Name, have all the parcels put into a list(so I can display in listbox on form).

My SQL skills are limited and I don’t know how I would go about doing something like this.

```
SELECT MHP_Parcel_Info.*, MHP.NUM_SITES FROM MHP_Parcel_Info INNER JOIN MHP ON " +
                "(MHP_Parcel_Info.MHP_NAME = MHP.MHP_NAME) WHERE MHP_Parcel_Info.MHP_NAME='" + strValue + "'"
```

Comment: Your query seems to be OK! Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, it works, but if there are more than one record it retrieves one.  Out of 8 records it will retrieve the 6th one or maybe the 4th.  How would I retrieve all if more than one exists?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can do directly in SQL. There's no way to select data in a parent/child structure in a SQL query - you have to do that as a post-processing step.

Since this is tagged as C# and Winforms I'm assuming this is from inside a .Net app. You will need to execute the query as you have it above, then in C# you can use the LINQ [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) extension method on the result to group the results into a list of [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) objects which use the name as the key, and has all of the parcel info as the items in the list.

Even better, if you are using (or can use) LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework you can just write a linq query that fetches the data from the database and does the grouping all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Haven't used LINQ before but I guess this is what it will take to get me to using it.

Comment: From what I've been reading online trying to use LINQ with MS Access is going to be a big headache.  Third party LINQ to ODBC providers or convert Access to SQL server.  Ugh.

Comment: You can still use LINQ without using LINQ to SQL. LINQ also includes the ability to query IEnumerable objects. You can run the SQL query as it stands now, and put the response in a List/IEnumerable. Then call .GroupBy on that list (make sure to add using System.Linq).